# Android layouts inside an HorizontalScrollView with all the same width

Tags: android

I have a vertical layout that at the bottom I have an `HorizontalScrollView`. Inside that `ScrollView` I want to display four containers and these containers should have the exactly same width.
Each one of these containers is loaded with a fragment that inflates an layout with width and height match_parent. I only populate the containers inside the `ScrollView` after making some network requests so after all data is loaded I can have this:

```
first_small_container_data      -> width = 100px
second_small_container_data     -> width = 200px
third_small_container_data      -> width = 230px
fourth_small_container_data     -> width = 112px
```

I want that, after the data is loaded, all the containers inside the `HorizontalScrollView` have all the maximum width, in this case `230px`.

I've tried to achieve this with the following layout but with no success.

**Any ideas how to solve this using only XML?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/big_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/second_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/small_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/small_container_data"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/first_small_container_data"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/second_small_container_data"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/third_small_container_data"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/fourth_small_container_data"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hz);



        /* Load Data */

        // After data is loaded
        // Set containers to maximum width: 230px;
        int maxWidth = 230;

        LinearLayout firstSmallContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.first_small_container_data);
        LinearLayout secondSmallContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.second_small_container_data);
        LinearLayout thirdSmallContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.third_small_container_data);
        LinearLayout fourthSmallContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.fourth_small_container_data);

        firstSmallContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( maxWidth, 20));
        secondSmallContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( maxWidth, 20));
        thirdSmallContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( maxWidth, 20));
        fourthSmallContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( maxWidth, 20));

    }
}
```

Comment: I like to add that you can replace those 20s with `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`

Comment: Sorry. Edited my question because only wanted to know if it is possible using only XML